# Apply the order of list to another lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list, with a specific order:

```
L = [1, 2, 5, 8, 3]
```

And some sub lists with elements of the main list, but with an different order:

```
L1 = [5, 3, 1]
L2 = [8, 1, 5]
```

How can I apply the order of `L` to `L1` and `L2`?

For example, the correct order after the processing should be:

```
 L1 = [1, 5, 3]
 L2 = [1, 5, 8]
```

I am trying something like this, but I am struggling how to set the new list with the correct order.

```
new_L1 = []
for i in L1:
   if i in L: 
      print L.index(i) #get the order in L
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you just want to sort `L1` and `L2` according to the index where the value falls in `L`.

```
L = [1, 2, 5, 8, 3]

L1 = [5, 3, 1]
L2 = [8, 1, 5]

L1.sort(key = lambda x: L.index(x))
L2.sort(key = lambda x: L.index(x))
```

Comment: Or just `key=L.index`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but can not imagine how this should *not* decrease the time for sorting from `O(n*log(n))` to `O(n*n*log(n))`. If this is the case, it's only feasible for small lists. For larger lists, one should probably build some sort of `O(1)`-lookup dictionary from the elements to their index in list `L`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way you can sort using List comprehensions:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 5, 8, 3]
>>> 
>>> L1 = [5, 3, 1]
>>> L2 = [8, 1, 5]
>>> 
>>> L1 = [i for i in L if i in L1]
>>> L2 = [i for i in L if i in L2]
>>> 
>>> L1
[1, 5, 3]
>>> L2
[1, 5, 8]
```